# Membership entity commerce join form

Tags: commerce

I'm using [Membership entity commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/membership_entity_commerce) (7.x-1.0-alpha2) for my website.
On the join page, I'd like to reorder the membership types : I got "**one month**", "**three months**" and "**one year**", but they don't show up in the desired order... Plus I would like to customize this form (hide description and term length). I've been trying to change different things in the module's code with no luck.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't edit the module's code directly. [Make a custom module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7) that will hold your changes.

Secondly, you can use [HOOK_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to [make changes to the form](https://www.drupal.org/node/651106).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I agree with the good practice reminder, the problem is I really can't understand where this specific page is built in the code, I mean this is actually no form at all, just a simple table with 'add to cart' html links...

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for the same thing : have a look at modules/membership_entity/modules/membership_entity_type around line 16 you'll find the query that retrieve membership types :
    $ids = db_query('SELECT id FROM {membership_entity_type}')->fetchCol();
I didn't know how to hook into this so I just added 
   order by weight
set the types weights through the UI and that worked good for me.